# modified the window size using gstreamer

Tags: c, gstreamer

hi everybody i search how can i change the dimensions of window with gstreamer and c API when i play a video ,someone have any idea how can i do that ?
for exemple with the gst-launch i use this code :

```
gst-launch -e videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=10/1, width=200, height=150 ! videomixer name=mix ! \
   ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=10/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix.
```

when i change the width to 900 and the height to 400 it's work fine ,but with c API when i try to do it with videoscale it doesn't work i have always a small window ,can help me please??
thank you

Comment: which gstreamer version are you using (0.10 or 1.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 0.10 version use videomixer2 plugin which can change the ouput size. So you can have something like that:

```
gst-launch -e videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=10/1, width=200, height=150 ! videomixer2 name=mix ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=10/1, width=1280, height=720 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=10/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix. -v
```